Images not displaying in GCP Manager in ArcGIS Pro Ortho Mapping
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.3. I am unable to view the drone images in the GCP Manager window which I block adjusted.  I have loaded the GCP file and photos using Import GCP button. I can see the GCP photos in GCP Manager. Why am I not able to see the drone images? I also installed ArcGIS Pro 3.0 and have the same issue. My laptop specs: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12800H 2.40 GHz processor with a NVIDIA T1200 laptop GPU with 1TB SSD and 64GB Ram.

Did you check the images while import? Any errors? Reimport done? Windows complaints about corrupted images? Mismatched coordinat/projection of project and imported images possible?
